# Is it possible to find out all deprecated functions in a project?

Tags: android, optimization, android-studio-3.0

I want to find **deprecated** functions from my Android Studio Project. I have older project i want to remove all deprecated function

Answer (score 6):

You can navigate to Analyze/Run Inspection by Name, then this:
[image]

..and this:
[image]

It will take some time to perform analysis.

Comment: Thanks @ror for helping me out